# How can I convert a Scala HashSet to a Python set using py4j?

Tags: scala, py4j

I have an object in Scala that returns a `Set[String]`:

```scala
object MyObject {
  val setOfStrings = Set[String]("string1","string2")
}
```

I can successfully refer to that val from my Python code (using Py4J) with this:

```py
jvm.com.package.MyObject.setOfStrings()
```

however I can't figure out how to do anything useful with it. I want to convert it into a python set.

I managed to do it using this:

```py
eval(
  str(
    jvm.com.package.MyObject.setOfStrings()
  )
      .replace("Set(", "{\"")
      .replace(")", "\"}")
      .replace(", ", "\", \"")
)
```

but that's a horrifically brittle way of achieving it and I'm assuming Py4J provides a much better way.

I'm aware that [SetConverter](https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html#converting-python-collections-to-java-collections) can convert a python set to a Java set, but I want to do the opposite. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `java.util.Set` on the Scala side, which [will be converted](https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html) by Py4J into the Python equivalent `MutableSet`.

If you don't want to use Java collections in your Scala code base, then you might want to convert a `scala.collection.immutable.Set` into its Java equivalent when you want to communicate with Python.

I didn't run this code, but you could probably do this:

```scala
object YourObject {
  val setOfStrings = Set[String]("string1","string2")
}

object ViewObject {
  import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
  def setOfStrings: java.util.Set[String] = YourObject.setOfStrings.asJava
}
```

and use it in Python:

```py
jvm.com.package.ViewObject.setOfStrings()
```

Note that in this case, you [won't be able to modify the collection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html). If you want to be able to update the view in Python and have the changes reflected back in Scala, then you'll have to use a `scala.collection.mutable.Set` in your Scala code.